# Referenced libraries are missing and ClassDefNotFound error

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Hi there) Recently I deployed my app to GAE and got errors executing app:
ClassDefNotFound and ExceptionInInitializer errors
The first error is referenced to a line

```
  AdWordsServices services = new AdWordsServices();
```

Full stack trace:

```
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.akolchin.mfroiapp.server.dispatch.ga.GetGaCampaignsHandler.fillCampaigns(GetGaCampaignsHandler.java:81)
    at com.akolchin.mfroiapp.server.dispatch.ga.GetGaCampaignsHandler.execute(GetGaCampaignsHandler.java:65)
    at com.akolchin.mfroiapp.server.dispatch.ga.GetGaCampaignsHandler.execute(GetGaCampaignsHandler.java:1)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.server.AbstractDispatchImpl.doExecute(AbstractDispatchImpl.java:154)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.server.AbstractDispatchImpl.execute(AbstractDispatchImpl.java:110)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.server.AbstractDispatchServiceImpl.execute(AbstractDispatchServiceImpl.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:44)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:587)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:303)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) Multibinder is not initialized
  at com.google.api.ads.adwords.jaxws.AdWordsJaxWsModule.configure(AdWordsJaxWsModule.java:40)
  while locating java.util.Set<java.util.Map$Entry<com.google.api.ads.adwords.lib.client.AdWordsServiceDescriptor$AdWordsSubProduct, com.google.inject.Provider<com.google.api.ads.common.lib.client.HeaderHandler<com.google.api.ads.adwords.lib.client.AdWordsSession, com.google.api.ads.adwords.lib.client.AdWordsServiceDescriptor>>>>
  at com.google.inject.multibindings.MapBinder$RealMapBinder$RealProviderMapProvider.initialize(MapBinder.java:461)
  at com.google.api.ads.adwords.jaxws.AdWordsJaxWsModule.configure(AdWordsJaxWsModule.java:40)

2) Multibinder is not initialized
  at com.google.api.ads.adwords.jaxws.AdWordsJaxWsModule.configure(AdWordsJaxWsModule.java:50)
  while locating java.util.Set<java.util.Map$Entry<com.google.api.ads.adwords.lib.client.AdWordsServiceDescriptor$AdWordsSubProduct, com.google.inject.Provider<java.lang.String>>>
  at com.google.inject.multibindings.MapBinder$RealMapBinder$RealProviderMapProvider.initialize(MapBinder.java:461)
  at com.google.api.ads.adwords.jaxws.AdWordsJaxWsModule.configure(AdWordsJaxWsModule.java:50)

3) Error injecting method, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.inject.spi.ProviderInstanceBinding.getUserSuppliedProvider()Ljavax/inject/Provider;
  at com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder$RealMultibinder.initialize(Multibinder.java:324)
  at com.google.api.ads.adwords.jaxws.AdWordsJaxWsModule.configure(AdWordsJaxWsModule.java:50)
  while locating java.util.Set<java.util.Map$Entry<com.google.api.ads.adwords.lib.client.AdWordsServiceDescriptor$AdWordsSubProduct, com.google.inject.Provider<java.lang.String>>>
  at com.google.inject.multibindings.MapBinder$RealMapBinder$RealProviderMapProvider.initialize(MapBinder.java:461)
  at com.google.api.ads.adwords.jaxws.AdWordsJaxWsModule.configure(AdWordsJaxWsModule.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.inject.spi.ProviderInstanceBinding.getUserSuppliedProvider()Ljavax/inject/Provider;
    at com.google.inject.multibindings.Indexer.visit(Indexer.java:139)
    at com.google.inject.multibindings.Indexer.visit(Indexer.java:43)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInstanceBindingImpl.acceptTargetVisitor(ProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder$RealMultibinder.initialize(Multibinder.java:332)
    at com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder$RealMultibinder$$FastClassByGuice$$94efefc8.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastMethod.invoke(FastMethod.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector$1.invoke(SingleMethodInjector.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector.inject(SingleMethodInjector.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:75)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer$InjectableReference.get(Initializer.java:147)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
    at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.multibindings.MapBinder$RealMapBinder$RealProviderMapProvider.initialize(MapBinder.java:469)
    at com.google.inject.multibindings.MapBinder$RealMapBinder$RealProviderMapProvider$$FastClassByGuice$$7fff4848.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastMethod.invoke(FastMethod.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector$1.invoke(SingleMethodInjector.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector.inject(SingleMethodInjector.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:75)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer$InjectableReference.get(Initializer.java:147)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer.injectAll(Initializer.java:92)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:173)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at com.google.api.ads.adwords.jaxws.factory.AdWordsServices.<clinit>(AdWordsServices.java:44)
    at com.akolchin.mfroiapp.server.dispatch.ga.GetGaCampaignsHandler.fillCampaigns(GetGaCampaignsHandler.java:81)
    at com.akolchin.mfroiapp.server.dispatch.ga.GetGaCampaignsHandler.execute(GetGaCampaignsHandler.java:65)
    at com.akolchin.mfroiapp.server.dispatch.ga.GetGaCampaignsHandler.execute(GetGaCampaignsHandler.java:1)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.server.AbstractDispatchImpl.doExecute(AbstractDispatchImpl.java:154)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.server.AbstractDispatchImpl.execute(AbstractDispatchImpl.java:110)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.server.AbstractDispatchServiceImpl.execute(AbstractDispatchServiceImpl.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_$1.run(Method_.java:171)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.privilegedInvoke(Method_.java:167)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke_(Method_.java:125)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke(Method_.java:44)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:587)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:303)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

or

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.api.ads.adwords.jaxws.factory.AdWordsServices
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:415)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:605)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:333)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:303)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:260)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:78)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:148)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:468)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and happens inside constructor. Locally all works fine but not for deployed ver.

I think the reason is that the part of referenced libs is missing for deployed version...
I guess GAE automatically takes all libs in war/WEB-INF/lib folder according to Java EE standart

Here's a peace of code I use to show classpath...

```
URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) (Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())).getURLs();
 for(URL url : urls)
 res+= url.toString() + "\n";
```

If you know the best way to show a classpath..show me plz)
So...What you think? What I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the missing jar to the war/WEB-INF/lib folder. Note that adding a jar to the build path is not enough - it will make the application run locally, but you still have to copy it to that folder.

If you use Eclipse, select your project and look in the Problems tab. You may see a warning there that a jar from the build path will not be available on the server. Right click on this warning, select "Quick Fix", and then "Copy..." option.

NB: You don't need the classpath. If something is missing from the classpath, your app won't compile and won't run at all - locally or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

ClassDefNotFound occurs when a class can't be found **or loaded** - in your circumstance it is likely that some static initialisation in this class or a class it depends on is failing.

Look in the class actually causing the exception for any static fields or blocks - one of these is probably failing because of the sandbox environment.

The full stack trace should reveal which line is causing an exception. If I had to guess, this class uses a factory or manager to access the file system or open a socket or something with similar restrictions.

Comment: It's right) AdWordsServices class has a static injector,which uses Guice library, if there are any issues in Guice it causes exception inside AdWordsServices...But...HOW TO SOLVE IT?.I added all needed latest libraries...It works locally but not at the server.This problem actually is solved by maven's dependencies changes....I'm not using maven project and don't know how to write dependencies to solve this problem

Comment: I added full stack trace to my message